# Azure Role for copying database from one subscribtion to another

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-sql-server

We have a team that owns a subscription on Azure, and often we need service tickets to copy the database from a production subscription to a dev subscription. As a dev, we are allowed to have access (reader role) to the data, but not through the contributor role on prod. It was proposed that devs have specific permissions to just allow them to copy. But does not look like there is a role that remains "reader" in a sense, but is permitted enough to copy. Technically, in this case, devs will not change anything on prod. They should only be able to copy to another subscription in which they have a contributor role

Looking for a solution that allows a dev to copy the database but does not allow any additional rights on production subscriptions. One way I could think is to create a hosted C# based utility that runs a PowerShell under a given service account, and this program could be triggered by an API call. Developers could be allowed to make an API call.

I am not an Azure expert, so not sure if the above solution is overkill. Are there other straightforward ways of achieving this.

Comment: Are you looking to copy only once or there would be requirement for subsequent copy process?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Azure Portal, PowerShell, and the Azure CLI do not support database copy to a different subscription.

[image]

You can use T-SQL to copy your database to a server in a different subscription. Make sure you use a login that has the same name and password as the database owner of the source database. Additionally, **the login must be a member of the `dbmanager` role or a server administrator, on both source and target servers.**

```
--Step# 1
--Create login and user in the master database of the source server.

CREATE LOGIN loginname WITH PASSWORD = 'xxxxxxxxx'
GO
CREATE USER [loginname] FOR LOGIN [loginname] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo];
GO
ALTER ROLE dbmanager ADD MEMBER loginname;
GO

--Step# 2
--Create the user in the source database and grant dbowner permission to the database.

CREATE USER [loginname] FOR LOGIN [loginname] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo];
GO
ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER loginname;
GO

--Step# 3
--Capture the SID of the user "loginname" from master database

SELECT [sid] FROM sysusers WHERE [name] = 'loginname';

--Step# 4
--Connect to Destination server.
--Create login and user in the master database, same as of the source server.

CREATE LOGIN loginname WITH PASSWORD = 'xxxxxxxxx', SID = [SID of loginname login on source server];
GO
CREATE USER [loginname] FOR LOGIN [loginname] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo];
GO
ALTER ROLE dbmanager ADD MEMBER loginname;
GO

--Step# 5
--Execute the copy of database script from the destination server using the credentials created

CREATE DATABASE new_database_name
AS COPY OF source_server_name.source_database_name;
```